# How can I use mwdumper with Postgresql command line

Tags: postgresql, mediawiki, dump

I was importing a MediaWiki database using mwdumper with MySql. Now I need to do the same thing, but using Postgresql.

Basicly I get a archive in this link:

http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20140903/

And I use  mwdumper program to get informations and put in my database.

This is the database script:

https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/HEAD/maintenance%2Fpostgres%2Ftables.sql

I created the database through this sql, and now I need to use mwdumper to put data in my database. 
I saw many links about this, but only to do in MySql.

Anyone know how to do this import using Postgres, using command line?

---

Mwdumper: www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MWDumper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot this question, but I found the solution, the command line to use **mwdumper** with **postgres** is:

### java -jar mwdumper-1.16.jar --format=pgsql:1.5 ARCHIVE.xml.gz | psql -U wikiUSER -d wikiDATABASE

The command isn't wrong, the errors that happen is because the mwdumper-1.16 convert xml to sql with wrong sintaxe.

This is a insert sql after convert mwdumper  (XML->PostgreSql):

*INSERT INTO revision (rev_id,rev_page,rev_text_id,rev_comment,rev_user,rev_user_text,rev_timestamp,rev_minor_edit,rev_deleted) VALUES (378187747,676,378187747,'**there is no such thing as \"Jr.\" in Russian names.  sincerely yours, X\\'ZZ\\'**',0,'198.240.130.75','2010-08-10 14:55:48',0,0);*

Analizing the same insert in my data base Mysql, the expected text in Postgres is:

*INSERT INTO (...) ,' **there is no such thing as "Jr." in Russian names.  sincerely yours, X\''ZZ\''** '*, (...).

For example:
To represent double quotes, mwdumper give a sintaxe **\"** , but to represent **"** in Postgres doesn't have \ , it's just **"**.  The same idea to others sintaxe errors.

When you solve all sintaxe errors you can dump perfectly.